# Wordpress extreme slow admin page - General performance issue

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, woocommerce

one of my wordpress/woocommerse websites is experiencing extreme slow performance on the admin pages.
Below is the status with php setup along with everything else:

```
`
### WordPress Environment ###

WC Version: 7.1.0
REST API Version: ✔ 7.1.0
WC Blocks Version: ✔ 8.7.5
Action Scheduler Version: ✔ 3.5.2
Log Directory Writable: ✔
WP Version: 6.1.1
WP Multisite: –
WP Memory Limit: 512 MB
WP Debug Mode: –
WP Cron: ✔
Language: el
External object cache: –

### Server Environment ###

Server Info: Apache
PHP Version: 7.4.33
PHP Post Max Size: 512 MB
PHP Time Limit: 300
PHP Max Input Vars: 1000
cURL Version: 7.64.0
OpenSSL/1.1.1n

SUHOSIN Installed: –
MySQL Version: 5.5.5-10.3.36-MariaDB-0+deb10u2
Max Upload Size: 256 MB
Default Timezone is UTC: ✔
fsockopen/cURL: ✔
SoapClient: ✔
DOMDocument: ✔
GZip: ✔
Multibyte String: ✔
Remote Post: ✔
Remote Get: ✔

### Database ###

WC Database Version: 7.1.0
WC Database Prefix: IY9IzE_
Συνολικό μέγεθος βάσης δεδομένων: 618.25MB
Μέγεθος βάσης δεδομένων: 439.22MB
Μέγεθος ευρετηρίου βάσης δεδομένων: 179.03MB
IY9IzE_woocommerce_sessions: Δεδομένα: 0.05MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.02MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_woocommerce_api_keys: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.03MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.02MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.06MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_woocommerce_order_items: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.02MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_woocommerce_order_itemmeta: Δεδομένα: 0.06MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.03MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_woocommerce_tax_rates: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.06MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_woocommerce_tax_rate_locations: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.03MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_woocommerce_shipping_zones: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.03MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_woocommerce_shipping_zone_methods: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_woocommerce_payment_tokens: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.02MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_woocommerce_payment_tokenmeta: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.03MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_woocommerce_log: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.02MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_actionscheduler_actions: Δεδομένα: 25.38MB + Ευρετήρια: 22.52MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_actionscheduler_claims: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.02MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_actionscheduler_groups: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.02MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_actionscheduler_logs: Δεδομένα: 24.39MB + Ευρετήρια: 11.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_ac_segments: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_admin_columns: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.02MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_aelia_dismissed_messages: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_aelia_exchange_rates_history: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_amuga_ajax_log: Δεδομένα: 3.52MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_atum_order_itemmeta: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.03MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_atum_order_items: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.02MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_atum_product_data: Δεδομένα: 1.52MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.97MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_aws_cache: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_aws_index: Δεδομένα: 6.47MB + Ευρετήρια: 6.66MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_commentmeta: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.03MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_comments: Δεδομένα: 0.05MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.09MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_ddp_log: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_eurobank_transactions: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_links: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.02MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_mclean_refs: Δεδομένα: 0.20MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_mclean_scan: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.02MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_options: Δεδομένα: 10.19MB + Ευρετήρια: 1.20MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_plugin_logic: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_pmlca_links: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_pmxi_files: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_pmxi_hash: Δεδομένα: 7.36MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_pmxi_history: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_pmxi_images: Δεδομένα: 13.52MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_pmxi_imports: Δεδομένα: 0.20MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_pmxi_posts: Δεδομένα: 2.52MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_pmxi_templates: Δεδομένα: 0.20MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_postmeta: Δεδομένα: 186.73MB + Ευρετήρια: 73.83MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_posts: Δεδομένα: 27.55MB + Ευρετήρια: 8.91MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_posts_bck: Δεδομένα: 31.55MB + Ευρετήρια: 12.06MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_posts_bck_2: Δεδομένα: 31.55MB + Ευρετήρια: 12.06MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_po_filtered_endpoints: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_revslider_css: Δεδομένα: 0.13MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.02MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_revslider_css_bkp: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.02MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_revslider_layer_animations: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_revslider_layer_animations_bkp: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_revslider_navigations: Δεδομένα: 0.05MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_revslider_navigations_bkp: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_revslider_sliders: Δεδομένα: 0.19MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.02MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_revslider_sliders_bkp: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.02MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_revslider_slides: Δεδομένα: 1.52MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.02MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_revslider_slides_bkp: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.02MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_revslider_static_slides: Δεδομένα: 0.05MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.02MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_revslider_static_slides_bkp: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.02MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_shortpixel_folders: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.02MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_shortpixel_meta: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.02MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_shortpixel_postmeta: Δεδομένα: 2.52MB + Ευρετήρια: 1.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_tdrd_log_details: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_tdrd_redirection: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_termmeta: Δεδομένα: 0.09MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.13MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_terms: Δεδομένα: 0.06MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.06MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_term_relationships: Δεδομένα: 4.52MB + Ευρετήρια: 2.52MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_term_taxonomy: Δεδομένα: 0.06MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.06MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_tm_taskmeta: Δεδομένα: 0.45MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.13MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_tm_tasks: Δεδομένα: 0.39MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.05MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_usermeta: Δεδομένα: 0.28MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.06MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_users: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.05MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_wccs_conditions: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_wccs_condition_meta: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.03MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_wc_admin_notes: Δεδομένα: 0.05MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_wc_admin_note_actions: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.02MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_wc_category_lookup: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_wc_customer_lookup: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.03MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_wc_download_log: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.03MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_wc_order_coupon_lookup: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.03MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_wc_order_product_lookup: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.06MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_wc_order_stats: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.05MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_wc_order_tax_lookup: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.03MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_wc_product_attributes_lookup: Δεδομένα: 0.41MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.36MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_wc_product_download_directories: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.02MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_wc_product_meta_lookup: Δεδομένα: 3.52MB + Ευρετήρια: 4.67MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_wc_rate_limits: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.02MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_wc_reserved_stock: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_wc_tax_rate_classes: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.02MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_wc_webhooks: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.02MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_wdp_orders: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.05MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_wdp_order_items: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.06MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_wdp_persistent_rules_cache: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_wdp_rules: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.03MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_wdr_order_discounts: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_wdr_order_item_discounts: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_wdr_rules: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_wpfm_backup: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.00MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_wpr_rocket_cache: Δεδομένα: 0.28MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.42MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_wpr_rucss_used_css: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.08MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_yith_wcwl: Δεδομένα: 0.06MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.02MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_yith_wcwl_lists: Δεδομένα: 0.06MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.05MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_yoast_indexable: Δεδομένα: 48.59MB + Ευρετήρια: 17.59MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_yoast_indexable_hierarchy: Δεδομένα: 1.33MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.91MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_yoast_migrations: Δεδομένα: 0.02MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.02MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_yoast_primary_term: Δεδομένα: 0.19MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.27MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.
IY9IzE_yoast_seo_links: Δεδομένα: 0.05MB + Ευρετήρια: 0.03MB + Μηχανή InnoDB.

### Post Type Counts ###

acf-field: 12
acf-field-group: 5
attachment: 27177
custom_css: 3
customize_changeset: 5
is_search_form: 1
mc4wp-form: 1
nav_menu_item: 121
page: 49
plgnoptmzr_work: 2
post: 7
product: 19197
product_variation: 386
revision: 123
shop_order: 21
ts_footer_block: 19
ts_logo: 43
ts_portfolio: 15
ts_team: 6
wc_conditional_fee: 1
wcp_ruleset: 1
wp_global_styles: 2
wpcf7_contact_form: 1
wpcode: 2

### Security ###

Secure connection (HTTPS): ✔
Hide errors from visitors: ✔

### Active Plugins (43) ###

Template Library and Redux Framework: από τον/την Extendify – 4.3.20
Admin Columns Pro - Advanced Custom Fields (ACF): από τον/την AdminColumns.com – 3.0.4
Admin Columns Pro - WooCommerce: από τον/την AdminColumns.com – 3.7.3
Advanced Custom Fields: Extended: από τον/την ACF Extended – 0.8.8.10
Admin Columns Pro: από τον/την AdminColumns.com – 5.7.4
Advanced Custom Fields PRO: από τον/την WP Engine – 6.0.4
Advanced Woo Search: από τον/την ILLID – 2.67
Auto Image Attributes From Filename With Bulk Updater: από τον/την Arun Basil Lal – 3.3
Conditional Payments for WooCommerce: από τον/την Lauri Karisola / WP Trio – 2.3.1
Conditional Shipping for WooCommerce: από τον/την Lauri Karisola / WP Trio – 2.3.1
Contact Form 7: από τον/την Takayuki Miyoshi – 5.6.4
Discount Rules and Dynamic Pricing for WooCommerce: από τον/την Asana Plugins – 6.7.1
Envato Market: από τον/την Envato – 2.0.7
Flexible Shipping: από τον/την Octolize – 4.16.2
Freesoul Deactivate Plugins: από τον/την Jose Mortellaro – 1.9.3.3
greeklish-permalinks: από τον/την Panagiotis Kontogiannis
elpak – 3.3

WPCode - Insert Headers, Footers, and Code Snippets: από τον/την WPCode – 2.0.3
WPBakery Page Builder: από τον/την Michael M - WPBakery.com – 6.9.0
Media Cleaner: από τον/την Jordy Meow – 6.5.0
Slider Revolution: από τον/την ThemePunch – 6.5.24
ThemeSky: από τον/την ThemeSky Team – 1.1.7
WooCommerce Smart COD: από τον/την woosmartcod.com – 1.6.1
CTX Feed: από τον/την WebAppick – 4.5.10
Έντοκες δόσεις από την Web Expert: από τον/την Web Expert – 1.0.4
Web Expert Eurobank WooCommerce Payment Gateway: από τον/την Web Expert – 1.0.36
WooCommerce Backorder Manager: από τον/την jeffrey-wp – 2.3
Woocommerce Bulk Price Update: από τον/την TechnoCrackers – 2.2.1
WooCommerce EU VAT Assistant: από τον/την Aelia – 2.0.36.221110
Gift Wrapper: από τον/την Sagehen Studio – 5.2.5
WP Menu Cart: από τον/την WP Overnight – 2.12.1
WooCommerce Min/Max Quantities: από τον/την WooCommerce – 4.0.4
WooCommerce Shipment Tracking: από τον/την WooCommerce – 1.9.0
WooCommerce: από τον/την Automattic – 7.1.0
Yoast SEO: από τον/την Ομάδα Yoast – 19.10
WP All Import Pro: από τον/την Soflyy – 4.7.8
WP Rocket: από τον/την WP Media – 3.12.2.1
Widget Disable: από τον/την required – 2.1.0
WP All Import - ACF Add-On: από τον/την Soflyy – 3.3.8
WP All Import - Link Cloaking Add-on: από τον/την Soflyy – 1.1.5
WP All Import - User Import Add-On Pro: από τον/την Soflyy – 1.1.8
WP All Import - WooCommerce Import Add-On Pro: από τον/την Soflyy – 3.3.4
Related Products for WooCommerce: από τον/την WebToffee – 1.4.6
Λίστα Επιθυμιών YITH WooCommerce: από τον/την YITH – 3.15.0

### Inactive Plugins (2) ###

Cloudflare: από τον/την Cloudflare
Inc. – 4.11.0

MC4WP: Mailchimp for WordPress: από τον/την ibericode – 4.8.11

### Dropin Plugins (2) ###

advanced-cache.php: advanced-cache.php
maintenance.php: maintenance.php


### Settings ###

API Enabled: –
Force SSL: –
Currency: EUR (€)
Currency Position: right
Thousand Separator: ,
Decimal Separator: .
Number of Decimals: 2
Taxonomies: Product Types: external (external)
grouped (grouped)
simple (simple)
variable (variable)

Taxonomies: Product Visibility: exclude-from-catalog (exclude-from-catalog)
exclude-from-search (exclude-from-search)
featured (featured)
outofstock (outofstock)
rated-1 (rated-1)
rated-2 (rated-2)
rated-3 (rated-3)
rated-4 (rated-4)
rated-5 (rated-5)

Connected to WooCommerce.com: ✔
Enforce Approved Product Download Directories: ✔

### WC Pages ###

Βάση καταστήματος: #51 - /shop-2/
Καλάθι: #52 - /cart-2/
Ταμείο: #53 - /checkout-2/
Ο λογαριασμός μου: ❌ Η σελίδα δεν περιέχει το shortcode [woocommerce_my_account].
Όροι και Προϋποθέσεις: #55963 - /oroi-chrisis/

### Theme ###

Name: Drile Child
Version: 1.0.0
Author URL: http://theme-sky.com/
Child Theme: ✔
Parent Theme Name: Drile
Parent Theme Version: 1.2.7
Parent Theme Author URL: http://theme-sky.com/
WooCommerce Support: ✔

### Templates ###

Overrides: drile/woocommerce/archive-product.php
drile/woocommerce/content-product-cat.php
drile/woocommerce/content-product.php
drile/woocommerce/content-widget-product.php
drile/woocommerce/loop/add-to-cart.php
drile/woocommerce/loop/loop-end.php
drile/woocommerce/loop/loop-start.php
drile/woocommerce/loop/orderby.php
drile/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php
drile/woocommerce/single-product/product-image.php
drile/woocommerce/single-product/product-thumbnails.php
drile/woocommerce/single-product/rating.php
drile/woocommerce/single-product/tabs/description.php
drile/woocommerce/single-product/tabs/tabs.php
drile/woocommerce/single-product.php


### Admin ###

Enabled Features: activity-panels
analytics
coupons
customer-effort-score-tracks
experimental-products-task
experimental-import-products-task
experimental-fashion-sample-products
shipping-smart-defaults
shipping-setting-tour
homescreen
marketing
multichannel-marketing
mobile-app-banner
navigation
onboarding
onboarding-tasks
remote-inbox-notifications
remote-free-extensions
payment-gateway-suggestions
shipping-label-banner
subscriptions
store-alerts
transient-notices
woo-mobile-welcome
wc-pay-promotion
wc-pay-welcome-page

Disabled Features: minified-js
new-product-management-experience
settings

Daily Cron: ✔ Next scheduled: 2022-11-18 08:15:32 +02:00
Options: ✔
Notes: 51
Onboarding: completed

### Action Scheduler ###

Canceled: 2
Oldest: 2022-11-09 16:37:32 +0200
Newest: 2022-11-17 13:01:24 +0200

Complete: 72.253
Oldest: 2022-11-17 15:41:48 +0200
Newest: 2022-11-17 16:41:08 +0200

Failed: 7
Oldest: 2022-11-15 11:13:30 +0200
Newest: 2022-11-17 13:12:16 +0200

Pending: 3
Oldest: 2022-11-17 16:42:08 +0200
Newest: 2022-11-18 15:50:05 +0200


### Status report information ###

Generated at: 2022-11-17 16:41:34 +02:00
`
```

The first thing someone will notice is that there is a big amount of plugins installed. Unfortunately all are needed and cannot be uninstalled.

One more thing is that the e-shop has almost 20.000 products, though only something like 2.000 published.

What we notice is that the CPU is skyrocketing whenever someone is logged in as admin and doing stuff like product editing etc.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3etly.png)

According to newrelic, me most time consuming are:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeAEj.png)

We have tried to optimize it but it seems we are in a dead end. I would really appreciate for any quidelines or suggestions.

We tried setting the amoung of php-fpm chidren to a higher value, also some caching, disabled some plugins but it still is extremely slow.

Comment: *"you can beat a horse to run faster but it wont be as fast as a 767"* - a slow performance issue can be attributed to many causes. one among them is the database overburdened then the application has to wait till the data comes in. the other would be the application itself getting swamped by the sheer amount of data and/or requests. or simply your hardware doesn't up to the tasks. what you need to do is to narrow down the root cause (e.g. trying to replicate the problem locally, **speaking of which, we can't**). getting to the bottom of a slow site is an arduous task.

Comment: *"What we notice is that the CPU is skyrocketing whenever someone is logged in as admin and doing stuff like product editing etc."* - from this statement, checking any plugin related to product is a good start. maybe disable them one-by-one, and see which one is the offending plugin.

Comment: anyway, welcome to stackoverflow! i suggest you to take a [tour] and learn [ask]. it would be nice if you could provide an [mcve] to work with!

Comment: Woo is based on WP; this helps WP a lot:  [_WP Index Improvements_](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/)

Answer (score 0):

The reason that can slow down the whole installation in this case is many more than one and simple answer.

The fact that you're using so many plugins makes the problem more complicated, but, you can start to focusing in the main sectors like web hosting, dev examination, etc.

You can sent me in PM the URL of installation to help much deeper?

Giorgos :)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. Silly question, how do i send PM here? I'm relatively new.

Comment: Kinda illegal to tell you according to community rules. You can provide a URL of your installation? I will fetch any necessary information!